# Why doesn't Ubuntu 20.04 LTS suspend completely, or if it does suspend, it won't resume?

Tags: suspend

Almost 15 years ago I switched from Windows to Ubuntu and almost everything worked out fine. Although I am a mere user, with little knowledge of command lines I have managed with a little help to fix minor problems, however in June of this year I decided to upgrade as version 18.04 will no longer have updates.

I upgraded to version 20.04, but since then I have had a lot of freezing problems: on the one hand, every time I set the suspend function, the system tries but cannot suspend completely; the screen turns off but the hard drive keeps working, but what is worse, it is absolutely impossible to resume (wake up) the system. On the other hand, from time to time, the system freezes unexpectedly, resulting in a waste of time and work.

I have an Intel Core i5 650 @ 3.20GHz × 4 CPU, 3.7 GB of memory and the GNOME version is 3.36.8. Does anyone know or have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: I do not quite understand how the freezing is related to the suspend/resume problem. It's unclear which issue you want answered. If either issue can be reliably reproduced in a test environment, please file a bug report for it.

Comment: The freezing happens when trying to resume and when loading or working with several programs. I presume a memory failure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: Thanks. I do presume a memory failure. I shall check the swap issue.